# Yii2 : Display the phone mask as text

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Tell me how to make the phone output in a readable way?

It is stored in the database as `1234567890`, but you need to display the user - `(123) 456-78-90`.

I do not want to make a garden, obvio,usly there are already ready solutions.

In Controller

```
public function actionShowPhone()
{
 $phone = "1234567890";
 return $this->render('show-phone', ['phone' => $phone,]);
}
```

In View show-phone.php

```
<?= Html::encode($phone) ?>
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then add more details to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Formatting phone numbers in Forms

If you are looking to format the phone number inside the `ActiveForm` you can use the [**`\yii\widgets\MaskInput`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput) in the following way

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'landline_phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
    'mask' => '(999)-999-99-99'
]);
?>
```

or without `ActiveForm`

```
echo \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
    'name' => 'phone',
    'mask' => '(999)-999-99-99',
]);
```

***Note: when saving the `phone` field you must save it as a number only in the database like `1234567890` so before you save you can use `$this->landline_phone= preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $this->landline_phone);` inside the `beforeSave()`.***

### Formatting Phone Numbers as Text

- **`Extending the \yii\i18n\Formatter`**

  But if you want to print the phone number as text in the above format then a good way is to extend the [**`yii\i18n\Formatter`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter) and create a custom component/helper in lets say `common\components\` or `app\components\` with the following code.

  *Note : change the `namespace` for the class accordingly*

  ```
  <?php

  namespace common\components;

  use yii\i18n\Formatter;

  class FormatterHelper extends Formatter {

      public function asPhone($value) {
          return preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/", "($1)-$2-$3-$4", $value);
      }

  }
  ```

  and then in the `common\config\main.php` or `app\config\web.php` add the following under `components`.

  ```
  'formatter' => [
      'class' => '\common\components\FormatterHelper',
      'locale' => 'en-US',
      'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
      'datetimeFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
      'decimalSeparator' => '.',
      'thousandSeparator' => ',',
      'currencyCode' => 'USD'
  ],
  ```

  then you can use it like below

  ```
  echo Yii::$app->formatter->asPhone('123456789')
  ```

  and it will output the following as text

  ```
  (123)-456-78-90
  ```
- **`Using \yii\widgets\MaskedInputAssets`**

  Another simplest and easiest way is to register the available `MaskedInputAssets` that uses [**`RobinHerbots/Inputmask`**](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) bundled and use javascript to mask the text

  ```
  <?php 
  \yii\widgets\MaskedInputAsset::register($this);

  $js = <<<SCRIPT
  var selector = document.getElementById("mask");
  var im = new Inputmask("(999)-999-99-99");
  im.mask(selector);
  SCRIPT;

  // Register tooltip/popover initialization javascript
  $this->registerJs ( $js , \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
  ?>
  <div id="mask">
     1234567890
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method helped me!